# what is the best way to show some piece of code or snippet in component template using ReactJS App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: for example i want to show my code like below image in template in front end.]

for example i want to show my code like above image in template in front end. can we use JSdoc or  tag for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use [React Syntax Highlighter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-syntax-highlighter), it lets you create snippets in different themes and languages.

Install the package

npm: `npm install react-syntax-highlighter`

yarn: `yarn add react-syntax-highlighter`

Example usage

```js
import SyntaxHighlighter from "react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/default-highlight";
import { dracula } from 'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/hljs';

<SyntaxHighlighter
  language="javascript"
  style={dracula}>
  {`code to display`}
</SyntaxHighlighter>
```

There are a lot of modification options (custom styling, line numbers...) that can be passed as props, read more about usage and modification on their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/react-syntax-highlighter/react-syntax-highlighter#props).

Comment: @satyadasari glad I could help, if you need further guiding let me know!